# Send thank you email for contact sign up

Tags: scheduled-reminders

I want to send a thank you for signing up as a supporter. There is no donation so this is done through using a profile in civicrm https://emptyhometax.org/civicrm/profile/create/?gid=2&reset=1

I have set up a reminder as shown below but it isn't working. Any suggestions?
[image]

Comment: do you have any other Sch. Reminders working? (if not, check your Sch. Job is running). have you tried +1 hour (in case the 0 hours is a gotcha)?

Comment: No I have never used reminders before. This is my first try at it. I will try the putting in 1 hr and test it now.

Comment: Do I have to set up a cron job to make this work?

Comment: You need a cron if you don't want to rely on running it manually

Comment: Yes. Got some help setting up the cron and the scheduled job that I set up to run "everytime cron runs" is now working smoothly triggering the reminders to go out upon sign up automatically. The zero field seems to fine as shown above.

Comment: added as an Answer - pls Accept and +1

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a cron job to run your Scheduled Reminders if you don't want to have to do this manually